# How to give parent border to nested children in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several widgets which are reusable.

```dart
class ReusableWidget extends StatelessWidget {

build(context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Text('my widget')
  );
}
```

They will be used in different layouts, in one of the layouts I need the page to have different borderRadius, so I decided to do something like this:

```dart
class LayoutWithRadius extends StatelessWidget {
final Widget child;

LayoutWithRadius(this.child);

build(context) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    child: child
  );
}
```

But the problem is that the radius will not be applied for the children containers, they have their own radius which will cover the parent's.

You have to note the child widgets themselves should not have radius for they are used in different layouts with different radius (and the radius should not be passed as parameter to widget).

Comment: how about using `ClipRRect` and creating different named constructor.

Answer (score 4):

change your LayoutWithRadius class to this

```
 class LayoutWithRadius extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double radius;
  const LayoutWithRadius(this.child, {super.key, this.radius = 20});

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```